# SQL Plus command line: Arrow keys not giving previous commands back

Tags: linux, sqlplus

I am using Oracle 10g Express Edition on Fedora core 5 32+ bit os. The problem is when I use the SQL Plus command line to make SQL statements I can not get the previously typed command back at the prompt when I use the up and down arrow keys on my keyboard. This is quite easy when I am using a shell, but here with this Oracle command line interface it is not working at all. Here is the example as what actually is happening whe I press the up or down arrow keys.

SQL> drop table mailorders;

Table dropped.

SQL> ^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A

Answer (score 20):

If you need rerun only the last command typed then the forwardslash "/" would work.
Hit / and then the enter key would rerun the last statement.

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
--------
03-12-17

SQL> /

SYSDATE
--------
03-12-17

SQL>
```

Answer (score 15):

The 'l' command will show the last run command ([source: krenger.ch](https://www.krenger.ch/blog/reuse-last-query-in-sqlplus-on-linux/)):

```
SQL> l
  1* select owner, count(1) from dba_tables group by owner
SQL>
```

To get more than that, turn on history ([source: dba-oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sqlplus_history.htm)):

```
SQL> set history on
SQL> history
  1  select * from dual;
  2  select sysdate from dual;
  3  show history
```

Comment: history command is a good option, [docs.oracle 18c here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/sqlplus-users-guide-and-reference.pdf#page=203). You can use `> hist 2 run ` to rerun second entry in history. Use `> help history` for help.

Comment: for 'set history on' - make sure you are on version 12.2 or higher for sqlplus as this is a newer feature

Answer (score 11):

SQL*Plus doesn't offer this feature out-of-the-box. You have to setup [rlwrap](https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/rlwrap) to get that going

We have built a new command line interface that supports everything SQL*Plus offers, but also includes more modern features such as previous command history. It's called [SQLcl](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/oracle-sqlcl-slidedeck-overview-of-our-new-command-line-interface/). The command history remembers your last 100 statements/scripts, even from previous sessions.

Comment: note i wrote this answer before SQLPlus added support for history. there are some big differences between sqlcl's history feature and sqlplus', so be aware of that

Answer (score 9):

in SQL plus command you can get you previous command by:

**1- show previous command**

```
SQL> history  
  1  l
  2  show history
  3  select * from dual;
```

**2- run specific command from previous**

```
SQL> history 3 run

D
-
X
```

**3- edit specific command from previous**

```
SQL> history 2 edit
```

PS: before using history you need to activated by:

```
SQL> set history on
```

Answer (score 1):

In few steps :

- Install `rlwrap` : https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/rlwrap
- Find the command `sqlplus` location : `which sqlplus` (lets say : `$SQLPLUS_HOME` is the folder where sqlplus is found)
- Go to this location : `cd $SQLPLUS_HOME`
- Rename sqlplus file for example : `mv $SQLPLUS_HOME/sqlplus $SQLPLUS_HOME/sqlplusplus`
- Create a new script named sqlplus : `vim $SQLPLUS_HOME/sqlplus`
- Put into it the command : `rlwrap sqlplusplus $@`
- Make it executable : `chmod u+x $SQLPLUS_HOME/sqlplus`
- Run : `sqlplus / as sysdba`, you will be able to navigate by up and down keys.